# Resolved: GitHub Pages deployment blank (Vite-React-TS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, github-pages

I've deployed my project to GitHub Pages, but the resulting site is blank.

The title I have given in the html `<title>` tag shows correctly on the browser tab. The entire page is just blank, however, and the following error is thrown in the console:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

The source of the console error is `main.tsx:1`. I have troubleshooted for several hours, and the fact that I still see the `.tsx` extension here makes me think that, somehow, the TS code is not being transpiled to JS, and the browser is therefore not able to parse it? I run `npm run deploy` when deploying.

Does anybody have any idea what's going wrong? :) Thank you. I have posted what I believe to be the relevant code snippets below, let me know if you need anything else.

**Update: Resolved**
When I woke up today after tinkering with several settings and repeatedly deploying last night, it suddenly works! I'm not sure which specific settings edit made the difference, so here are a few of the things that I did towards the end that seemed to make a difference:

**In vite.config.ts, change**

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

to

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/guess-the-wiki/",
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

**In index.html, change**

```
<script type="module" src="./src/main.tsx"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="module" src="./src/main"></script>
```

**On github ->  -> settings -> pages -> build and deployment -> branch**

Change `main` to `gh-pages`

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "guess-the-wiki",
  "homepage": "https://djbalin.github.io/guess-the-wiki/",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.node.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

**vite.config.ts:**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
// import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/guess-the-wiki/",
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

Comment: What does the `dist` directory look like? Also, how did you create this project? If you used the `vite` setup did you template it with TypeScript, like: `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template react-ts`?

Comment: Dude thank you @JanBalin, I have been bashing my head on this problem for hours, and I gave up on a similar project months ago for the same thing. Your edits here worked for me and I am finally seeing my vite typescript + react page deployed on github pages.